# How to move the bottom div to infront of the top one

Tags: html, css

I need help with moving the profile-options div.
Here's an image so I can show you what I mean, the code is provided below the image.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JE3Zt.png)

index.html

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="info">
            <div id="profile" name="picture">
                <img src="https://scontent-frt3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/17021559_243918039403378_4935600322061460678_n.jpg?oh=aa472121820d78b6116c91d47557bce6&oe=59738E5C" name="profile" />
                <img src="https://scontent-frt3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/17098689_244217759373406_3036940291705168436_n.jpg?oh=5f7b2ead37fdec3c2b13fa60fe431a0c&oe=5924FEA8" name="frontpage" />
            </div>
            <div id="menu" name="profile-name">
                Random Guy
            </div>
            <div id="menu" name="profile-options">
                Hi
            </div>
            <div id="personal">
                <ul>
                    <!-- fields about the user profile -->
                    <li>Password: *****************************</li>
                    <li>Country: Bosnia & Herzegovina</li>
                    <li>City: not choosen</li>
                    <li>Address: not choosen</li>
                    <li>Phone number: not choosen</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

style.css

```
#page #content #info #profile[name="picture"]
{
    width:700px;
}

#page #content #info #profile[name="picture"] img[name="profile"]
{
    width:128px;
    height:128px;
}

#page #content #info #profile[name="picture"] img[name="frontpage"]
{
    width:572px;
    height:128px;
    margin-left:-4px;
}

#page #content #info #personal
{
    width:698px;
}

#page #content #info #menu[name="profile-name"]
{
    background-color:#d8d8d8;
    width:116px;
    height:48px;
    max-width:116px;
    max-height:48px;
    border:0px;
    padding:6px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    margin-top:-5px;
}

#page #content #info #menu[name="profile-options"]
{
    background-color:#d8d8d8;
    width:572px;
    height:48px;
    border:0px;
    margin-top:-5px;
}
```

How can I achieve this without using any position commands or margin, I tried left:0px and top:0px but did not work. 
‎
‎
‎
‎
‎
‎
‎
‎

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#menu {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zkmuxayq/

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the float left property:

```
#page #content #info #menu[name="profile-name"]
{
    background-color:#d8d8d8;
    width:116px;
    height:48px;
    max-width:116px;
    max-height:48px;
    border:0px;
    padding:6px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    margin-top:-5px;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add 'float:left/right' to both of them and make sure their width sum is not larger than 100%.

```css
.div {
position:relative;
float:left;
height:50px;
}

.left {
width:20%;
background-color:grey;
}

.right {
width:80%;
background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<div class="div left"></div>
<div class="div right"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues.
First of all, ids must be unique and you have 2 "menu" ids.
To achieve what you want, you have to set "display: inline-block" to the 2 divs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a float left to profile-name. Currently if you inspect that element you can see it is taking up the full width of the screen.

```
#page #content #info #menu[name="profile-name"]
        {
            background-color:#d8d8d8;
            width:116px;
            height:48px;
            max-width:116px;
            max-height:48px;
            border:0px;
            padding:6px;
            word-wrap:break-word;
            margin-top:-5px;
            float: left
        }
```